# How to click on marker produced by places API and find the lat/long of that marker and then upload to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using the places API to show places as markers on my map, I then want to be able to click on one of markers and save its information to firebase. At the moment when I save it to firebase it saves my current location instead of the markers lat long. pls help :)

mStar is the button that is clicked that once clicked I want to add the location to firebase...

```
mStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Rating......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;*/

        LocationInformation locInfo = new LocationInformation(name, latitude, longitude);

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();

        saveLocations.child(userID).child("Locations").setValue(locInfo)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Location saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Error location not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    }
});
```

this is the whole class as per requested in the comments.. thank you!!!!!

```
//imports
public class NearbyLocations extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private String name, selPlace;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private Marker currentUserLocationMarker;
    private static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;
    private ImageButton mStar, mHeart;
    private LatLng selPlaceLatLng;
    private String apiKey = "AIzaSyAiXcwMQY9v2ba4GvxLPsF_G-FPUJA5DUU";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference saveLocations;

    private int ProximityRadius = 10000;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_locations);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            checkUserLocationPermission();
        }

        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);

        // Create a new Places client instance.
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        saveLocations = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mStar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStar);
        //mHeart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnHeart);


        mStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //mHeart.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            buildGoogleApiClient();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }


        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                mStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               // mHeart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                return false;
            }
        });



        /*AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });*/



       mStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Rating......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /*latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;*/

                LocationInformation locInfo = new LocationInformation(name, latitude, longitude);


                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String userID = user.getUid();
                saveLocations.child(userID).child("Locations").setValue(locInfo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Location saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Error location not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });


            }
        });




    }

    public void starClick(Marker marker){
        Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Rating......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /*public void heartClick(Marker marker) {


        Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "savig......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


         /*latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
         longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        LocationInformation locInfo = new LocationInformation(name, latitude, longitude);


        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        saveLocations.child(userID).child("Locations").setValue(locInfo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Location saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(NearbyLocations.this, "Error location not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });*/


    /*public void pinClick(){

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {


                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Clicked Location"));

            }
        });

    }*/





    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();



    }



    public boolean checkUserLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location_Code);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location_Code);

            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case Request_User_Location_Code:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        if (googleApiClient == null ){
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        lastLocation = location;

        if (currentUserLocationMarker != null){
            currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("user Current Location");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

        currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(12));

        if(googleApiClient != null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);

        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String hotel = "hotel";
        String night_club = "night_club";
        String restaurant = "restaurant";
        Object transferData[] = new Object[2];
        GetNearbyPlaces getNearbyPlaces = new GetNearbyPlaces();

        //String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude);


        switch (v.getId())
        {
            /*case R.id.search_address:
                EditText addressField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location_search);
                String address = addressField.getText().toString();

                List<Address> addressList = null;
                MarkerOptions userMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(address))
                {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

                    try
                    {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 6);

                        if (addressList != null)
                        {
                            for (int i=0; i<addressList.size(); i++)
                            {
                                Address userAddress = addressList.get(i);
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(userAddress.getLatitude(), userAddress.getLongitude());

                                userMarkerOptions.position(latLng);
                                userMarkerOptions.title(address);
                                userMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                                mMap.addMarker(userMarkerOptions);
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please write any location name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;*/


            case R.id.hotels_nearby:
                mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, hotel);
                transferData[0] = mMap;
                transferData[1] = url;

                getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Showing Nearby hotels...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


            case R.id.clubs_nearby:
                mMap.clear();
                url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, night_club);
                transferData[0] = mMap;
                transferData[1] = url;

                getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Showing Nearby Night Clubs...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


            case R.id.restaurants_nearby:
                mMap.clear();
                url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, restaurant);
                transferData[0] = mMap;
                transferData[1] = url;

                getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Showing Nearby Restaurants...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }


    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace)
    {
        StringBuilder googleURL = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googleURL.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googleURL.append("&radius=" + ProximityRadius);
        googleURL.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
        googleURL.append("&sensor=true");
        googleURL.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyAvKd4mDYNodZp-WfsT_AfpyyleH4BrKOI");

        Log.d("NearbyLocations", "url = " + googleURL.toString());

        return googleURL.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuLogout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                break;

            case R.id.menuProfile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.menuAllUsers:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AllUsers.class);
                this.startActivity(intent1);
                break;

            case R.id.accountDetails:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, UpdateProfile.class);
                this.startActivity(intent3);
                break;

            case R.id.menuLocation:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(intent2);
                break;

        }


        return true;
    }




}
```

Comment: Can you please post a code where `latitude` and `longitude` are assigned? because in the given code that part is commented. It would be good if you could post code for whole class.

Comment: What is happening when you are using `latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude`?  Please responde sith @AlexMamo

Comment: @MayurGajra posted the rest of the class, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code i found that you are assigning `latitude` and `longitude` inside `void onLocationChanged(Location location)` and that is why you are getting current location while clicking on star.

You should assign `latitude` and `longitude` inside onclick of marker as following.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Remove any other assignments and then click on star button,you should get proper location.

Comment: This still didnt work :( what do u mean by remove any other assignments? could u pls suggest what i would put in my starClick method to get the markers location to save to firebase? thank u!

Comment: By removing any other assignments i mean do not assign `latitude` and `longitude` except for `onMarkerClick` method,remove it from methods like `onLocationChanged` and then check,can you please do that and update me what you get?